# What is the meaning of "Enqueued" and "Dequeued" messages in "DLQ"?

Tags: activemq-classic

[image: Screenshot from 3 difference servers]

Hi guys ,

I'm now working with ActiveMQ and wanna know what is the meaning of enqueued/dequeued messages in DQL. As i know, DLQ doesn't have a consumer to produce any messages. So, there shouldn't have any enqueued or dequeued messages in DLQ queue. Am I right ? or there is another process to perform with pending queues in DLQ. Please advise.

Thanks,
Stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DLQ is just a JMS Queue behind the scenes, you can send message to it and consume messages from it just like any other queue...hence the stats, etc.

Comment: Ok. DLQ is just a JMS like others queues but my point is why DLQ display a statics of enqueued/dequeued messages ? This queue should not have another process except to keep an undelivered messages (or any messages with problem) and show only statics in No. of pending messages. Right ?

Comment: the console is generic and doesn't distinguish between DLQ and other queues...but like I said, its just a queue and therefore can have other producers/consumers (generally just consumers to triage/cleanup messaging errors, etc.) using it...the stats are completely relevant to see how many messages have flowed in/out, etc...

Comment: So, can I say that the enququed/dequeued messages in DLQ are mean the messages which already cleaned out from DLQ ?

Comment: The accepted answer does not answer the question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786086/difference-between-pending-messages-and-enqueue-counter-in-active-mq